# Error in Tensorflow Inception V3 geting while pool_3 layer output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to get the pool_3 layer output of the tensorflow inception v3. My input is ndarray of shape (64,64,3) but I get following error

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    pool_3_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')

    feat1 = sess.run(pool_3_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image})  
    feat1 = np.squeeze(feat1)
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-fb1865f7fbee> in <module>()
      3     pool_3_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')
      4 
----> 5     feat1 = sess.run(pool_3_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image})
      6     feat1 = np.squeeze(feat1)

/N/u/mbirla/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    765     try:
    766       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 767                          run_metadata_ptr)
    768       if run_metadata:
    769         proto_data = 
    tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/N/u/mbirla/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    942                 'Cannot feed value of shape %r for Tensor %r, '
    943                 'which has shape %r'
--> 944                 % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
    945           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
    946             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 64, 3) for Tensor 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0', which has shape '()
```

-------Update----------

After converting it into string. I am getting Invalid JPEG data, size 12288.
For detailed error: https://gist.github.com/mridulbirla/0d710d7ccd7b22c8f87989c37837e10e

Answer (score 0):

change

```
feat1 = sess.run(pool_3_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image})
```

into

```
feat1 = sess.run(pool_3_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image.tostring()})
```

and have a try

`'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'` is a scalar string tensor from which you can decode a three dim image tensor

---

When I did transfer learning with inception-v3,  I didn't read image into np.array type, instead, read the image content to a string with

```
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("you_image_file_name") as f:
     content = f.read()
```

then feed the `content` to `'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'`

Comment: If i convert it to string , then I am getting InvalidArgument Error  . Detailed stacktrace [Error link](https://gist.github.com/mridulbirla/0d710d7ccd7b22c8f87989c37837e10e)